# Delphi and beacons - AllBeaconsScanner example

Tags: android, delphi, ibeacon

I use Delphi 10.4, Samsung 10 (Android 10) and ibeacons

Example "AllBeaconsScanne" from Embarcodero, for me it works very well under windows 10 (detect my beacons), but on Android it does not detect any beacons. Does anyone know why?

BeaconScope application from google play detects without any problem

Comment: do you get any error? for `android` you for example have you set all the required `bluetooth` permissions? in latest version of android you need to ask user explicitly in addition to declaring in the `android manifest`.

Comment: Problem solved. Locations must be additionally allowed.

Comment: Yes for android many times it came down to these explicit permissions

Comment: @Olaf You should answer yourself to your question so that other reader will find the solution easily and your question marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Locations must be additionally allowed